# When Running 64-bit File on 64-bit Lubuntu Receive message: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: 15.04, lubuntu, 64-bit, c++

I am running Lubuntu 15.04 64-bit, and want to learn to code with SFML. I made a program just as a test:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1366, 768), "Welcome Screen");

    return 0;
}
```

Upon running it I receive the error:

```
bash: ./EOTL: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I have g++-4.9 installed and ran:

```
g++ -c -o EOTL main.cpp -libsfml-graphics -libsfml-window -libsfml-system
```

Please help me, and thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I guess g++ is very picky so I had to run:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o EOTL
```

Comment: The `-c` option tells gcc to stop short of the link phase, resulting in a bare object file rather than an executable program: rerun your gcc command without the `-c` and try again.

Comment: If I do that, it will not compile.

Comment: If it fails to build due to link errors (unresolved symbols), then that's probably because you aren't actually linking the relevant libraries - perhaps `-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system` (or an equivalent `pkg-config` command). Are you following some sort of tutorial?

Comment: I figured it out, g++ is a bit weird. I had to run : g++ -c main.cpp -o EOTL

Comment: @taserman21 - this site uses a Q&A format, please add a answer below with details into how you fixed it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason this does not work is that, for some reason g++ is picky about the order of the options. To compile correctly you must run:

```
g++ -c example.cpp -o example -libsfml-graphics -libsfml-window -libsfml-system
```